# openjdk: How to avoid fully recompilation of jdk after I modify jdk's code?

Tags: java, jvm

In openjdk8 source code, if I modify some places of hotspot source code, and then I use `make hotspot-only`, it will do an incremental compilation. But after I modify source code of jdk, when I use `make jdk-only`, I'm getting the message `Compiling 9495 files for BUILD_JDK`! Only a fully compilation will I get when I add only one line code just like a `System.out.println()`. How to avoid that?

Comment: Is this related to JDK only or C++ in general?

Comment: @Cargeh JDK only! Hotspot has an incremental compilation, when I modify something, the compilation will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

This happens more often when using Make's `.PHONY` targets.

If your target is a `.PHONY` target, or references a `.PHONY` target, then 
try to find a set of rules that produce the same output without using the `.PHONY` target.

`.PHONY` targets in make trigger rules unconditionally, which is useful when you really don't want to write a lot of `Makefile` to just trigger the required portions of a build.  While they have their uses (especially in the `make clean` pattern), they often perform more work than needed, which is the problem you've identified.

If you find a `.PHONY` rule in your make processing, and you cannot avoid it, you may need to restructure / rewrite the Makefile to fix it.

From your description, it sounds like `hotspot-only` is the real target, and `jdk-only` either is a `.PHONY` target or references a `.PHONY` target that includes "everything" in a rebuild.  That might be by design or accident, but at least now you know why the rebuild happens.